# Two representations of a finite group have no irreps in common if and only if their characters are orthogonal.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

We want to prove that two representations of a finite group $\Gamma_{1}$ and $\Gamma_{2}$ have no irreducible representation in common if and only if their characters are orthogonal, i.e.,

$\sum_{k=1}^{c} n_k \chi_{1k}\chi_{2k}^{*}=0$,

where $\chi_{1k}$ and $\chi_{2k}$ are the characters of the $k-$th class in $\Gamma_{1}$ and $\Gamma_{2}$ respectively.

We can say that for common irreps the characters are the same and therefore the above relation doesn't equal to zero. But it is trivial. Could you please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
\Gamma_1 \sim \bigoplus_{\alpha\in\widehat{G}}m_\alpha^{(1)}\Gamma_\alpha, \qquad \Gamma_2 \sim \bigoplus_{\alpha\in\widehat{G}}m_\alpha^{(2)}\Gamma_\alpha
$$
be the decompositions of $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ into irreducible representations. Here $\widehat{G}$ denotes the equivalence classes of irreducible reps of $G$, $\Gamma_\alpha$ denotes a specific representation in the class $\alpha$, and $m_\alpha^{(i)}$ denotes the multiplicity of the $\alpha$ in $\Gamma_i$. Taking the trace of both sides gives
$$
\chi_{\Gamma_i} = \sum_{\alpha\in\widehat{G}}m_\alpha^{(i)}\chi_\alpha
$$
for $i=1,2$. Defining the inner product
$$
\langle a, b \rangle := \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\overline{a(g)}b(g)
$$
and using orthonormality of the irreducible characters $\chi_\alpha$ gives
$$
\langle \chi_{\Gamma_1}, \chi_{\Gamma_2}\rangle = \sum_{\alpha\in\widehat{G}}m_\alpha^{(1)}m_\alpha^{(2)}.
$$
Since the $m_\alpha^{(i)}$ are non-negative integers, this equals zero iff $m_\alpha^{(1)}m_\alpha^{(2)} = 0$ for all $\alpha\in\widehat{G}$. This is true iff for each $\alpha\in\widehat{G}$, either $m_\alpha^{(1)} = 0$ or $m_\alpha^{(2)} = 0$, i.e. $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ have no irreducible representations in common.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Nice!